# Error while loading shared libraries (file: magfieldmapper_gui)

Tags: 18.04, libraries, executable, shared-library

I am new to unbuntu. Please help me with this issue if possible. I have read through many solutions online, yet I am having difficulties understanding what was written by most.

I tried to run an executable from the terminal, however this is the error message that followed.

```
./magfieldmapper_gui: error while loading shared libraries: liblapacke.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please advice. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This most likely means that the library your program is looking for is not installed. To find out what package this library is in, do this (if **apt-file** is not found, run `sudo apt install apt-file && sudo apt update` first):

```
apt-file search liblapacke.so.3
```

Your output will be something like this:

```
liblapacke: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapacke.so.3
```

So, install the package as normal:

```
sudo apt install liblapacke
```

---

---

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response!

Comment: Now there seems to be another problem, the next output is  

`./magfieldmapper_gui: error while loading shared libraries: libcholmod.so.3.0.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`   

I have tried the same method, as you mentioned, however this time, the error message is  

`E: Unable to locate package libcholmod3.0.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libcholmod3.0.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libcholmod3.0.6'`  Sorry for troubling you.

Comment: On my Mint system (same base as Ubuntu 18.04), I'm on libcholmod.so.3.0.11.

Comment: Yes I understand Sir, however, it seems that this executable requires an older version of libcholmod for it to run. Do you have any idea how I can alter this?

Comment: OK. You can try downloading the right version from Ubuntu and installing it, but you may run into more dependency problems.

Comment: I appreciate your help greatly. I hope you have a nice day.